# Mocking a key away from os.environ

Tags: python, mocking

I'm trying to test a function that should return an OSError if it can't find a specific key in os.environ, but I can't figure out how to mock it.
I'm fine with mocking os.environ completely empty as well.

`with mock.patch.dict('os.environ', dict()):
    print(os.environ)`

or

`with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, dict()):
    print(os.environ)`

Will print my entire environment regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I've resorted to MonkeyPatching the os.environ instead:

`old_os_environ = os.environ
        try:
            os.environ = {}
            self.assertRaises(OSError, my_function)
        finally:
            os.environ = old_os_environ`